# Chinese characters encode error when move database from aws to google cloud sql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, unicode, utf-8, google-cloud-platform

We have a website which is dealing with ***Chinese characters*** and was hosted on **AWS**.

Here I can save ***Chinese characters*** in database without any problem.

Now we move to **Google Cloud** and I am facing issue saving Chinese characters in database.

**They display as ä¸€åœ°å…©æª¢**

I am following all rules like "column should be **utf8-unicode-ci**" and "database connection as **utf8**".

It is working fine on localhost.

Any Idea what can be problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data (column) in the database holds (similar) UTF8-encoded data in both cases and the code/platform which handles the data in the web-page is the same (meaning not python 2 vs  python 3 for example), the difference might be the current local setting, either of the Google server (environment-variables), the SQL-client (UTF8-settings) or the php-settings.
Lets start with the sql-client: 
Try to run the php - function

```
mysqli_character_set_name()
```

to get the encoding. If it is not UTF-8 then set it with

```
mysqli_set_charset('utf8')
```

If this is not working ensure the php-html stuff by setting the charset in the META html-tag to utf-8

```
charset=utf-8
```

and enforce it with

```
declare(encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: I am using php and database version is 5.6

Comment: Ok, I assume this environment here  [link] (https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/using-cloud-sql-with-mysql)  Start with comparing the supported database locals [link] (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode.html) . If this is ok then the problem could be in the client, check local settings on your Linux (Google) platform to your previous platform [link] (https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-locales-i18n-on-a-linux-unix/) Note: If you are using the MySQL database version 5.x check that your (ODBC?) client is also 5.x (or supports that)

Comment: I tried above link , but not helping. All thing utf8

Comment: I found one thing here , may be it will help. When I run direct insert query using sqlyog I can insert Chinese characters but they are not inserting properly when using php

Comment: Yes we are getting nearer. The problem is either in the web page META settings or in the settings of the SQL-client php is using. Lets start with the sql-client: Try  to run the php - function "mysql_client_encoding" to get the encoding. If it is not UTF-8 then set it with "mysql_set_charset( 'utf8' )" If this is not working ensure the php-html stuff by "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> " and enforce it with "declare(encoding='utf8')"

Comment: Hi , Gunnar , Its working now. You can post a good answer based on above discussion  and I will mark this as accepted answer so it can help others also. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok great, you pointed me in right direction so i added a hat too (can do that now). I will edit the original answer

Comment: Do _not_ use PHP's `mysql_*` interface; use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.

Comment: @GunnarSigfusson - Please do not use any conversion routines.  They are likely to make things worse, in which case it will be much more difficult to unravel things.

Comment: Yes it is not necessary here to use the iconv. I was not familiar with the lot of stuff php offers. My world is more in the C/Python and unfortunately I need it in my work as I have to save messages of different encodings in same column in database and fewer convertion options in C, but it is not necessary here. I also will re-edit the answer to mysqli_* and remove iconv - comments

Comment: @GunnarSigfusson - thanks for updating.  One more thing: `mysqli_client_encoding()` has been removed from PHP and replaced by `mysqli_character_set_name()`.  Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-client-encoding.php

Comment: @RickJames Updated the answer with set_name function thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have `latin1` somewhere in the processing.

`ä¸€åœ°å…©æª¢` is "Mojibake" for `一地兩檢`

See Mojibake in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Some Chinese characters take 4 bytes, not just 3 bytes.  So, I recommend you use `utf8mb4`, not simply `utf8`.

Comment: Thanks , The answers you linked in is really helpful to understand things.